# Can not install anything via apt. No module named 'flask'

Tags: flask, apt, dpkg

This is what I get every time I want to install any package via apt and make && make install:

```
Setting up pgadmin4-apache2 (4.23-1.pgdg18.04+1) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 18, in <module>
    from pgadmin.model import db, User, Version, ServerGroup, Server, \
  File "/usr/share/pgadmin4/web/pgadmin/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    from flask import Flask, abort, request, current_app, session, url_for
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask'
dpkg: error processing package pgadmin4-apache2 (--configure):
 installed pgadmin4-apache2 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 pgadmin4-apache2
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I have flask installed:

```
$ which flask
/home/anna/.local/bin/flask
$ whereis flask
flask: /usr/bin/flask /usr/local/bin/flask /home/anna/.local/bin/flask
$ python -m flask --version
Python 2.7.17
Flask 1.1.2
Werkzeug 1.0.1
```

but:

```
$ python3 -m flask --version
/usr/local/bin/python3: No module named flask
```

tried to install flask by both pip and pip3:

```
$ pip3 install flask
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: flask in /home/anna/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (1.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: click>=5.1 in /home/anna/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from flask) (7.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: itsdangerous>=0.24 in /home/anna/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from flask) (1.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: Jinja2>=2.10.1 in /home/anna/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from flask) (2.11.2)
Requirement already satisfied: Werkzeug>=0.15 in /home/anna/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from flask) (1.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: MarkupSafe>=0.23 in /home/anna/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from Jinja2>=2.10.1->flask) (1.1.1)
```

What can I do to fix that?

UPD: I removed pgadmin4-apache2 and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
sudo pip3 install flask
```

or

```
python3 -m pip install flask
```

as you are getting site-package is not writeable, with sudo you are super user

You can also work in python3 environment and install packages there only.

Comment: Try creating environment with any default packages with python 3.6, then start working in it. I was facing same issue(python 3.8) and tried with 3.6, it works fine

Comment: Thanks! I created conda env with python3.6 which has flask. But when I run sudo apt-get install, the python version is 3.8 that doesn't even have pip. Making alias in bashrc can't affect "sudo" commands. Can you please tell how to make "sudo apt-get"  use only python3.6, not python 3.8?

Comment: @user14008482 Please uninstall anaconda-python completely then try : 
`cd /tmp`
`curl -O https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/Anaconda3-2019.03-Linux-x86_64.sh`
`sha256sum Anaconda3-2019.03-Linux-x86_64.sh`
`bash Anaconda3-2019.03-Linux-x86_64.sh`
`source ~/.bashrc`
`conda create --name env_name python=3.6 --no-default-packages`
`conda activate env_name`
`pip/pip3 install packages`

Answer (score 0):

As @Bramhesh mentioned using apt is the wrong way to go.

Normally you should use:

```
pip3 install flask
```

To check your already installed modules use:

```
pip3 freeze
```

Sometimes you run into errors during installation e.g. when you don't have write rights in the direction your python environment is saved.

Then use:

```
sudo pip3 install flask
```

But as it seems you already have a flask module installed. You can upgrade this by using:

```
pip3 install flask --upgrade
```

Cheers!

Comment: "Requirement already satisfied" in all cases. Installing packages via pip/pip3 works fine, but sometimes I need to install something that isn't in pip. I can't run "configure" and "make" either because of that error "No Module named flask"